# python split string into multiple delimiters and put into dictionary

Tags: python

i have the below string that i am trying to split into a dictionary with specific names.

```
string1 = "fdsfsf:?x=klink:apple&nn=specialtime&tr=instruction1&tr=instruction2&tr=instruction3"
```

what I am hoping to obtain is:

```
>>> print(dict)

{'namy_names': 'specialtime', 'tracks': ['instruction1', 'instruction2', 'instruction3']}
```

i'm quite new to working with dictionaries, so not too sure how it is supposed to turn out.

I have tried the below code, but it only provides `instruction1` instead of the full list of `instructions`

```
delimiters = ['&nn', '&tr']

values = re.split('|'.join(delimiters), string1)
values.pop(0)  # remove the initial empty string
keys = re.findall('|'.join(delimiters), string1)
output = dict(zip(keys, values))

print(output)
```

Comment: Where does `namy_names` come from?

Comment: `namy_names` comes from `&nn` which I hope to rename (if possible). same with `tracks` which comes from `&tr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use url-parsing.

```
from urllib import parse

url = "fdsfsf:?x=klink:apple&nn=specialtime&tr=instruction1&tr=instruction2&tr=instruction3"
d = parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(url).query)

print(d)
```

Returns:

```
{'nn': ['specialtime'],
 'tr': ['instruction1', 'instruction2', 'instruction3'],
 'x': ['klink:apple']}
```

And from this point, if necessary..., you would simply have to rename and pick your vars. Like this:

```
d = {
    'namy_names':d.get('nn',['Empty'])[0],
    'tracks':d.get('tr',[])
}

# {'namy_names': 'specialtime', 'tracks': ['instruction1', 'instruction2', 'instruction3']}
```

Comment: This seems to have an extra key, but I don't think that can be helped.

Comment: Thanks both for your comments! I think I will accept this answer because it returns me all the items as a dictionary item, and then I can just rename and take what I want / need. Might be good for other people viewing this answer.

Comment: @Anton vBR, was hoping you can share more about the last section of the codes for the renaming of the `keys`? What is `['Empty']` and `[]`?

Comment: @jakewong Those are defaultvalues. So let's say that the first dictionary does not have any 'nn' then it returns ['Empty'] and same with tracks. Try for instance to pass a string without those params.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like url-encoded data, so you can/should use [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```
import urllib.parse

string1 = "fdsfsf:?x=klink:apple&nn=specialtime&tr=instruction1&tr=instruction2&tr=instruction3"

dic = urllib.parse.parse_qs(string1)
dic = {'namy_names': dic['nn'][0],
       'tracks': dic['tr']}
# result: {'namy_names': 'specialtime',
#          'tracks': ['instruction1', 'instruction2', 'instruction3']}
```

Comment: @coldspeed Well, yes. I *could* add a way to configure which key is renamed to what and whether each key should be a list or a string, but I think that's probably over-engineered.

Comment: Thanks @Aran-Fey for your answer!